# Map fixed length string to an integer

Tags: r, string, hash

suppose I like to map any combination of string of length k into integers (if count only 26 latters uppers and lowers I will have (26+26) ^k combination.
Is there a fast way in r to map, given string of length k into unique integer?

For example:
1. Say for k=1 and c("a","d","z"), then the result will be c(1,4,26).
2. Say for k=2 and c("aa","da","zA"), then the result will be c(53,157,1379).

Comment: If you had 16 letters your question would be equivalent to how to transform hexadecimal numbers to decimal numbers. Your base is 52, but the same algorithms can be used.

Comment: I have a string of length k, when k is large (say 10), I need a fast method to map it to an integer. I don't know in advance the string to map, only the fixed length of k.

Comment: I've just told you a fast way.

Comment: For a start you should study this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavigesimal

Comment: How can I treat a string as a number in say 52 base? Do you know a function that tack string and convert it to number in some base? What about the other symbols like "?",":"," ","!" and so on?

Comment: There is function `strtoi`, but it only accepts bases up to 36. You need to implement this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
conv <- function(strings, base = letters) {
  s <- strsplit(strings, "") 
  vapply(s, function(x, base) {
    x <- match(x, base)
    as.integer(t(x) %*% (length(base)^(rev(seq_along(x)) - 1L)))
  }, 1L, base=base)
}

#test it
strtoi("5A3", base=16)
#[1] 1443
conv("5A3", base=c(1:9, LETTERS[1:7]))
#[1] 1443

mystring <- c("a", "d", "z", "aa","da","zA")
conv(mystring, base = c(letters, LETTERS))
#[1]    1    4   26   53  209 1379
```

Other symbols can be included easily in the `base` parameter.